# adding tapku library to Xcode5

Tags: tapku

I am very new to mac and iOS or any programming. I would like to add tapku library in to my Xcode project. I have download the file and saved it in /developer/shared/Documentation/docsets folder. I do not know what to do next. I red some document which says "Clone the TapkuLibrary git repository git clone git://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary.git.".....i do not have any idea where i should type and perform the cloning...any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance
Magesh

Answer (score 2):

You can install `tapku` through `cocoapods` by just adding `pod 'TapkuLibray','~>0.3'` in your `Podfile`, then run `pod install`, and tapku will be installed automatically.

For more information about `cocoapods`,see http://cocoapods.org/

Comment: Unable to find a specification for `TapkuLibray`

Comment: Can you please guide what should I write in pod file.

Comment: @ShreeshGarg Just add `pod 'TapkuLibrary'` to your Podfile, and run `pod install`.